# Iterate over files, ignoring filenames with a hyphen

Tags: bash, imagemagick

## Background

Converting images from RGB to grayscale. A number of files exist in different directories. For example:

```
outline/trigon.png
outline/oval-bw.png
outline/crescent-bw.png
outline/trigon-bw.png
outline/crescent.png
outline/oval.png
```

## Problem

Iterate over a set of files (without a hyphen) and convert them to grayscale, without including files that have already been converted. Files that have already been converted have file names ending with `-bw.png`. The script should avoid creating `-bw-bw.png` files.

## Solution

The following line will iterate over only the files that have not been converted:

```
for i in $(find ./stripe/ ./outline ./solid -name "*.png" -exec echo {} \; | grep -v "-"); do
```

The full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Avoid converting existing B&W files...
for i in $(find ./stripe/ ./outline ./solid -name "*.png" -exec echo {} \; | grep -v "-"); do
  SHAPEDIR=$(dirname $i)
  SHAPENAME=$(basename $i .png)
  OUTPUTSHAPE=$SHAPEDIR/$SHAPENAME-bw.png
  echo "convert $i to $OUTPUTSHAPE ..."
  convert $i -density 600 -colorspace gray $OUTPUTSHAPE
done
```

## Question

What's a simpler way to iterate over all files while ignoring any file that has a hyphen (e.g., `-bw`) in its name? (Using `find` and `echo` and `grep` seems obtuse.) This is an academic question, as the solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash extended globbing patterns:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo outline/!(*-*)
outline/crescent.png outline/oval.png outline/trigon.png
```

Comment: Since that pattern alone would match other things apart from `png`, I suggest this one instead: `for i in @(stripe|outline|solid)/@(!(*-bw).png); do`.